# How to reset SQL Contrains in Python Odoo

Tags: python, sql, odoo

I have the below `_sql_contraints` in a module and I am just trying to override one of the rules defined here.

```sql
   _sql_constraints = [
        ('type_value',
         "CHECK((holiday_type='employee' AND employee_id IS NOT NULL) or "
         "(holiday_type='company' AND mode_company_id IS NOT NULL) or "
         "(holiday_type='category' AND category_id IS NOT NULL) or "
         "(holiday_type='department' AND department_id IS NOT NULL) )",
         "The employee, department, company or employee category of this request is missing. Please make sure that your user login is linked to an employee."),
        ('date_check2', "CHECK ((date_from <= date_to))", "The start date must be anterior to the end date."),
        ('duration_check', "CHECK ( number_of_days >= 0 )", "If you want to change the number of days you should use the 'period' mode"),
    ]
```

I would like to take out this line and remain the rest of the constrain as it is

`(holiday_type='company' AND mode_company_id IS NOT NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

By removing `"(holiday_type='company' AND mode_company_id IS NOT NULL) or "` this line of code from your constraint.

```
 _sql_constraints = [
        ('type_value',
         "CHECK((holiday_type='employee' AND employee_id IS NOT NULL) or "
         "(holiday_type='company' AND mode_company_id IS NOT NULL) or "
         "(holiday_type='department' AND department_id IS NOT NULL) )",
         "The employee, department, company or employee category of this request is missing. Please make sure that your user login is linked to an employee."),
        ('date_check2', "CHECK ((date_from <= date_to))", "The start date must be anterior to the end date."),
        ('duration_check', "CHECK ( number_of_days >= 0 )", "If you want to change the number of days you should use the 'period' mode"),
    ]
```